# What is the preferred way to extract SQL from a tbl_dbi as a string?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I would like to extract the SQL from a tbl_dbi and save it as a character vector.

I have tried

```
library(dplyr)
my_tbl_dbi <- tbl(conn, "myTable")

my_query <- capture.output(show_query(my_tbl_dbi), type = message) %>%
    paste0(collapse = " ")
```

This worked for me in the past but now is not working, perhaps because I was playing around with the sink function. My question is "Is there a more robust/standard way to pull out the SQL query from a tbl_dbi or is what I am doing the only way to do it?"

Comment: `as.character(db_sql_render(my_tbl_dbi$src$con, my_tbl_dbi))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr This is much better than my solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think I read somewhere the output of these two solutions might be different, as I think `show_query` shows optimised sql, and not `db_sql_render`

Comment: still you should put it as an answer @hrbrmstr ;)

Comment: Given that it pretty much just calls `db_sql_render()`, it's unlikely, @Moody_Mudskipper (as you'll see in the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
as.character(db_sql_render(my_tbl_dbi$src$con, my_tbl_dbi))
```

Note:

```
methods("show_query")
## [1] show_query.tbl_lazy* show_query.tbl_sql* 

dbplyr:::show_query.tbl_sql
## function (x, ...) 
## {
##     message("<SQL>\n", db_sql_render(x$src$con, x))
##     invisible(x)
## }
## <environment: namespace:dbplyr>
```

The source for `db_sql_render.DBIConnection()`:

```
db_sql_render.DBIConnection <- function(con, sql, ...) {
  qry <- sql_build(sql, con = con, ...)
  sql_render(qry, con = con, ...)
}
```